# Should I inform prospective employers that I resigned from my old job after applying?

Tags: job-search, resignation

I am interviewing at a couple of places and although I was employed when I applied, I have now finished up with my current employer.

Is there any upside to letting these new employers know this, keeping in mind that I would like an offer asap?

Comment: At worst they may think you misunderstood the status of your application. I wouldn't say anything unless they seem to delay getting you a decision.

Comment: Well yes, my interest lies in pushing them to get me an offer quickly, do companies prefer candidates who are recently unemployed so they can't paddle back on leaving their current job or because they are immediately available?

Comment: Sometimes putting the boot on the other foot is a useful hint. If a company tells you, "the guy currently doing the job has quit already, would you please quit your job and join us tomorrow?", what would you do?

Comment: Don't mention it directly, but if they ask "when can you start?" you may tell them you can start with short notice.

Answer (score 18):

Your decision to leave the old job before you had the new job nailed down is not the new employer's problem, and telling them is about as likely to hurt you (by raising questions about how and why you left) as to help you. I'd suggest not mentioning it.

Comment: I agree, there is nothing positive about mentioning it.

Comment: It might even give them the idea that they can low-ball your offer because you don't have any other income.

Answer (score 1):

Most companies like to see that you are a valued worker, and they place a higher priority on that perception than on your immediate availability. Being currently unemployed is likely to be seen as a negative until you have a chance to explain, which you may or may not get the chance to do.

It will be far more valuable for you to let them know that you're interviewing with multiple companies, so if they delay they may lose you. If I were in your situation, I would use that fact first, and when asked about availability, simply mention that you can be available to start working within a day or two. Of course they'll wonder about why you're available so soon, but by then they will have decided that they're interested in you, and you will have a chance to explain why you have already left your previous employer.